# клиент с чистым WebSocket протоколом для AspNET Core signalR сервера

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core

клиент с чистым WebSocket протоколом для Asp net core signalR сервера.

Здравствуйте начал пробовать Aspnet core signalR сервер.

Для этого сервера написал 2 клиента: javaScript клиент с веб страны и десктоп WinForms клиент.
Для этой связки все хорошо работает.

```
   // Конфигурация проекта сервера:
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\Js\" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview1-final" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>


   // Конфигурация проекта javaScript клиента для signalR:
    {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "name": "signalrapp",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-preview1-update1"
      }
    }

   // Конфигурация проекта WinForms (.NET461) клиентадля signalR:
      ... Куча зависимостей для .net core
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" version="1.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="net462" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" version="1.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="net462" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" version="1.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Возникла необходимость подключить еще 1 клиента, который использует WebSocket и написан на Java!!!!!.
Хотел эмулировать Java клиента, написав примерно тоже на C# WinForms (.NET461), только используя не SignalR библиотеку, а чистый webSocket.
Подскажите можно ли использовать клиента с чистым WebSocet для SignalR сервера и что для этого надо?
например регистрируем отдельный хаб который пишет и читает в stream WebSocet массив byte. (без вызова RPC методов, как в signalR).

Еще слышал про centrifugo. Может есть какие нибудь аналогичные кроссплатформленные сервисы, которые работают на фоне (например как служба RabbitMq) и обеспечивают коммуникацию.
Заранее всем спасибо!!